# Does Jackrabbit allow deletion of files?

Tags: java, file, cron, jackrabbit

In my application I need to delete files older than 6 months.
Is it better to do this with a cron job or with Jackrabbit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better done through the JCR API, because Jackrabbit needs also to update the database files.